# Not able to register a new database

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, netbeans-7.1

I am using netbeans 7.1 and i have a database on server (not on my computer). I try to register it to netbeans for my application purpose. But when i try to register the database i get the following error :

> cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://69.144.150.5:3366/DCQ using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Communications link failure  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

Please help me to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking that the JDBC connection string. The default port for mysql is 3306. Should the string be `jdbc:mysql://69.144.150.5:3306/DCQ`?